# How to discover where a software user interaction sound file is located when it's being played from an application?

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, file-location

I wish to modify a sound that plays when a user clicks a selection in a piece of software (Grid 3). Currently, it's a 'mouse click' sound, so I can presume it's not synthesized on the fly (like a speech engine). I wish to modify the sound to a 60hz sine wave to drive tactile haptic feedback mechanism.

How can I discover where this file is? Presumably, my sound card knows where it is when it's playing it. Can I monitor this somehow?

Comment: So the question is how to find the source of the mouse click sound in “Grid 3?” Do you want to sample it?

Comment: No, I wish to modify it (to a 60hz sine wave to drive a tactile haptic feedback mechanism)

Comment: Grid 3 appears to be a software package to develop interfaces. Is this mouse click sound in an interface developed using grid 3 or is it a feature of the software package itself?

Comment: I am also wondering if you tried changing the default windows mouse click sound (via windows control panel > sound ) to see if it is simply calling the windows API for the click.

Comment: You could use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which audio files are opened by this software.

Comment: @Yorik feature of the software package. Already tried the Windows sound, and it's different. Thanks

Comment: @harrymc I tries that, but with no joy. Any advice on how to get that working? I used path > contains .wav / .mp3

Comment: Are you using Process Explorer or Process Monitor? I though in Process Explorer that is run as Admin to display the Handles view for the process, sort by type, then examine those of type File.